imin-printer.min.js:6 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8081/websocket' failed Error Show in Imin Printer Connect
HTML And JavaScript File is link in this HTML file and code in Writer By ref
Link
Error:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JS Printer Plugin DEMO</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Connecting IMIN</h1>
    <!-- <button></button> -->
</body>

</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mui/3.7.1/js/mui.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-5LSZkoyayM01bXhnlp2T6+RLFc+dE4SIZofQMxy/ydOs3D35mgQYf6THIQrwIMmgoyjI+bqjuuj4fQcGLyJFYg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss-sg.imin.sg/web/iMinPartner/js/imin-printer.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oss-sg.imin.sg/web/iMinPartner2/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/vConsole/3.9.1/vconsole.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Instantiate the print plugin
    //  var IminPrintInstance = IminPrinter();
    var IminPrintInstance = new IminPrinter();
    console.log("before Connect")
    //Create a webosket connection
    IminPrintInstance.connect().then(async (isConnect) => {
        // The websocket status is linked
        if (isConnect) {
            console.log("after Connect");
            // 1. initPrinter
            IminPrintInstance.initPrinter();
            // 2. getPrinterStatus
            const status = await IminPrintInstance.getPrinterStatus();
            console.log('Printer status:' + JSON.stringify(status));
            // 12. printText
            //  IminPrintInstance.printText('iMin advocates the core values of "Integrity, Customer First, Invention&Creation, Patience”, using cloud-based technology to help businesses to get access to the Internet and also increases their data base, by providing more solutions so that their business can take a step further. Through their efficiency enhancement, cost improvement, service JSPrintDemoDoc.md 2022/11/11 3 / 4 innovation, and better services for consumers, these aspect will drives the entire industry development.')
            // ...more print methods
        }
    }).catch(async (ex) => {
        console.log(ex);
    })
</script>

